# C++ Convert string to TCHAR*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Below is my code :

```
string szDllPath = "12345";
size_t size = szDllPath.length();
TCHAR* wArr = new TCHAR[size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    wArr[i] = _T(szDllPath[i]);

cout<<szDllPath<<endl;
cout<<wArr<<endl;
```

And I get this :

[image]

I don't understand why I get the extra characters, and how to solve it ?

Comment: You need to add the terminating null character `wArr[size] = '\0';`. Obviously you need to declare  `TCHAR* wArr = new TCHAR[size + 1];`

Comment: Just **don't**. Don't use Microsoft's `TCHAR` abomination. It's support for providing a limited functionality version of  your program for Windows 9x, and it was obsolete already in the year 2000 with the introduction of Layer for Unicode. Since Microsoft discontinued tool support for Windows 2000 and earlier all that stuff has in turn been obsolete. So it's an obsoleted technology that's been replaced by a now in turn obsoleted technology, addressing a problem that you have to travel back in time to encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to provide space for and add a terminating zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

New code should not be using [Generic-Text Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szdfzttz.aspx). They were invented in the 90's to ease porting code from ANSI systems (Win9x) to Unicode systems (Windows NT). `TCHAR` expands to either `char` or `wchar_t` controlled by the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbols.
**Don't use `TCHAR`, unless you have to support Win9x.**

**Analysis:**

You are making this way more complicated, than it is. Since this code

```
TCHAR* wArr = ...;
cout << wArr << endl;
```

writes a character string to `cout` (vs. a pointer value), you haven't defined the preprocessor symbols `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE`. In other words: You are using MBCS character encoding (see [Unicode and MBCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0.aspx)), and the following would produce identical output:

```
string szDllPath = "12345";
cout << szDllPath.c_str() << endl;
```

If that is really what you want (and I doubt it is), then simply calling [std::basic_string::cstr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is sufficient (use [std::basic_string::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), if you need a mutable string).

**Recommended solution:**

Use Unicode throughout. The following solves your immediate problem, if you are using a character string literal.

```
wstring szDllPath = L"12345";
wcout << szDllPath.c_str() << endl;
```

If you aren't using a character string literal and do need to convert from a `std::string` to a wide character string, you can use MFC's [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) class to perform the conversion:

```
CStringW wideString(szDllPath.c_str());  // Conversion c'tor, taking a const char*
const wchar_t* = (LPCWSTR)wideString;    // Invoke operator LPCWSTR()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when working with char* variants of strings in C and C++. They're required to have a terminating 0 at the and, and you didn't provide the space for it

```
TCHAR* wArr = new TCHAR[size+1];
...
/*add a terminating zero after the loop*/
wArr[size] = 0;
```

It would work as expected.

Also, avoid such bare char* operations if you can.